# Kubernetes: no such host for modify hostname slave

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

Version: kubeadm and kubectl 1.12

I get this error when I change the hostname of one of the Kubernetes slaves.

The error I get from the metric service:

```
dial tcp: lookup ops-kube-slave-dev-1 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
```

This IP is not the public or private IP and is completely random.

I add this to the file /etc/hosts:

```
10.0.1.248 ops-kube-slave-dev-2
10.0.1.154 ops-kube-slave-dev-1
```

When I execute `$ nslookup ops-kube-slave-dev-2`, I get the correct IP.

But still the same error. I want to avoid that for every new node I add to create a new certificate again.

What is the best solution for auto join slave node?

Comment: Why you edit and you put the command line with $ , I want to just copy all the line and just run :S

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to provide `--hostname-override` option to the kubelet configuration (in my case, /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf). Let you allow to change the kubernetes nodename without regenerating the certificates.

For more info, see https://prefetch.net/blog/2017/12/30/getting-your-kubernetes-node-names-right/.

PS: On the secondary note,The IP you're talking about is not random, that is the IP of kubedns service of your cluster. You can check it using `$ kubectl get svc -n kube-system`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks i will tried it,
/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS --hostname-override  
I change the last line of the config file and i add the --hostname-override but the service don't start

Comment: You need to provide the new hostname of your worker node to it, like --hostname-override=<hostname> . I hope you are doing it on the worker node which name you want to change